# Attribute title change with jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can change value with my code. I want to change attribute value jQuery toggle  when click `data-original-title` `test-1`  change to `test-2`.  How can I do that?

```
<i class="heart fa fa-heart" id="demo1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="test-1"></i>

$("#demo1").click(function() {
  $(this).attr("data-original-title", "test-2");
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine, you are just missing the `#` i guess!

Comment: Yea, it's a typo. Just add `#demo1` instead and it should work.

Comment: try this $(this).attr("data-original-title",$(this).attr("data-original-title")=='test-2' ?  "test-1" : "test-2"  );

Comment: @rayan005 Kindly check out my answer and see if it works... `:D` Have added all the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me this way. Look into the comments for the changes and corrected syntax errors:

```js
$(function () { // Add this ready function.
  $(".fa").tooltip();
  $("#demo1").click(function() {
    // Use a ternary function to change the tooltip when clicked.
    $(this).attr("data-original-title", $(this).attr("data-original-title") == 'test-2' ? "test-1" : "test-2" );
  }); // Error here.
}); // Add this as well.
```

```css
body {margin: 25px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<i class="heart fa fa-heart" id="demo1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="test-1"></i>
```

**Remember:** The change of tooltip is not instant. It changes only after you click and once the current tooltip is hidden.

**Preview**

First Click:

[image: first]

Second Click:

[image: second]

Third Click:

[image: first]

And so on...

Comment: Could also change tooltip text easily...default insertion makes it `next()`

Comment: Your Code worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle the `attribute` simple using `ternary if statement` like this

```
$(this).attr("data-original-title",$(this).attr("data-original-title")=='test-2' ?  "test-1" : "test-2"  );
```

```js
  $("#demo1").click(function() {

        $(this).attr("data-original-title",$(this).attr("data-original-title")=='test-2' ?  "test-1" : "test-2"  );
        console.log($(this).attr("data-original-title"));

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="heart fa fa-heart" id="demo1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="test-1">ss</i>
```

Comment: Please comment or explain what you have done. And running the snippet doesn't even work.

Comment: That ternary doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Your ternary code has issues. Mine works.

Comment: @JYoThI Thanks. But still nothing works in your answer as expected.

Comment: it's working well you can use developer tool inspect to see the output @PraveenKumar

Comment: @JYoThI Wait I don't get you. See my answer quickly. That's the expected one... `:/` All I see is an _ss_ in your snippet. Am I not right?

Comment: can you please check my snippet now @PraveenKumar

Comment: @JYoThI That's fine. I need to thank you as well. But you aren't getting the point of using tooltip. I have already seen that this works. `:)` Okay, enjoy buddy... `:D`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#demo1").click(function() {
  var val = $(this).attr("data-original-title");
  if(val == 'test-2') {
    $(this).attr("data-original-title", "test-1");
  } else {
    $(this).attr("data-original-title", "test-2");
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Another answer that doesn't explain what has been done. Why? Please comment or explain what you have done. And running the snippet doesn't even work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data()` instead of `attr()`. Secondly, you can use `on()`, in case, the element is gonna added dynamically. Just hover over and check the results:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".fa").tooltip();
});

$("#demo1").on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr("data-original-title", $(this).attr("data-original-title") == 'test-2' ? "test-1" : "test-2");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25px;
}

#demo1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<i class="heart fa fa-heart" id="demo1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="test-1"></i>
```

Comment: Nice answer. But it isn't changing from test-1 to test-2. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm you are right. For some reason, `data()` isn't updating the property. changed to `attr()` and it worked. your solution is correct.